# bash script rename multiple files

Tags: bash, shell

Let´s say I have a bunch of files named something like this: bsdsa120226.nai bdeqa140223.nai and I want to rename them to 120226.nai 140223.nai. How can i achieve this using the script below?

```
#!/bin/bash
name1=`ls *nai*`
names=`ls *nai*| grep -Po '(?<=.{5}).+'`
for i in $name1
    do
    for y in $names
        do
            mv $i $y
        done
    done



Solution:
name1=`ls *nai*`

for i in $name1
do
y=$(echo "$i" | grep -Po '(?<=.{5}).+')
mv $i $y
done
```

Comment: try this `(?<=^.{5}).+`

Comment: @AQT, it makes little sense to put an _answer_ in your question, it sort of breaks the whole Q&A concept. Just accept the answer that you think is right. If none were, and you have an answer, _post_ it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only bash, you could do this:

```
for file in *nai* ; do
  echo mv -- "$file" "${file:5}"
done
```

<sub>(Remove the `echo` when satisfied with the output.)</sub>

[Avoid `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), except for displaying information. Use plain globbing instead.

See also [How do I do string manipulations in bash?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for more string manipulation techniques.

---

Your script can't work with that structure: if you have 5 files, it will call `mv` five times for the first file (once for each element in the second list), five times for the second, etc. You'd need to iterate over the two sets of names in lockstep. (It also doesn't deal with things like whitespace in filenames.)

Comment: Does the rename command work on Centos/Redhat?

Comment: There's a rename command but it's not what has been mentioned in some of the other answers here (much more limited, doesn't support regexes). You can probably install it though, it's just a perl script.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob
for file in *+([[:digit:]]).nai; do
    echo mv -nv -- "$file" "${file##+([^[:digit:]])}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if you're happy with the `mv` commands.

**Note.** This solution *does not* assume that there are 5 leading characters to delete. It will delete all the leading non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using `rename` (`prename` on some systems) since that allows you to use Perl regular expressions to do the renaming, along the lines of:

```
prename 's/^.{5}//' *.nai
```

The reason your *script* is not behaving is that, for *every* source file, you're attempting to rename it to *every* target file.

If you need to limit yourself to using that script, you need to work out the *single* target file for *each* source file, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.nai; do
    y=$(echo "$i" | cut -c6-)
    mv "$i" "$y"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If your system has  `rename` tool, it's better to go with the simple `rename` command,

```
rename 's/^.{5}//' *.nai
```

It just remove the first 5 characters from the file name.

**OR**

```
for i in *.nai; do mv "$i" $(grep -oP '(?<=^.{5}).+' <<< "$i"); done
```

Comment: Occasionally called `prename` (Perl rename) on some systems, in case the `rename` you have doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Avinash, hence my comment "in case" :-)

Comment: Ok thanks any idea why my script does not work?