# Bash rename files with underscore

Tags: sed, rename

I have files that are named     CULT_2009_BARRIERS_EXP_Linear.dbf
    and  would like to rename them to 
    CULT_BARRIERS_EXP_Linear.dbf . 
 The files have a date prefixed with them which is always different      showing when it was captured.
  I have tried to replace them with regular expressions. i want to test     the string if it contains numbers and then rename. I have used

```
    if [[  $file =~ [0-9]   ]];  then rename -v "s/[0-9]//g" * && rename -v s/[_]_/_/ *;
```

which partially works. But I would ideally like to have one rename command as it is good practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash script rename multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589900/bash-script-rename-multiple-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single rename command would be enough. Just run the below command on the directory where `.def` files are actually stored.

```
rename -v "s/_[0-9]+//g" *.dbf
```

`[0-9]+` matches one or more digits where `[0-9]` will match a single digit character. `+` repeats the previous token one or more times.

Comment: or `rename -v "s/_[0-9]+//g" *`

Comment: or `if [[  $file =~ [0-9]   ]];  then rename -v "s/_[0-9]+//g" *; fi`

Comment: thanks . So [0-9] only replaces the first digit while the + recursively looks for any digits

Comment: yep, `+` repeats the previous token one or more times.